# Calling Model Method Via Django Rest Framework View

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)

    def plus_one(self):
        self.size += 1
        self.save()
```

And I have a simple serializer for this:

```
class SizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Size
        fields = '__all__'
```

How can I call a plus_one model method from my view, using DRF?
How is it callable, what is good practice for that? Thanks!

Added:

```
class SizeAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SizeSerializer
    queryset = Size.objects.filter()
```

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner made, but this is just abstaract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you right you need to call `plus_one` each time when object updated. In this case you can override `perform_update()` method like this:

```
class SizeAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SizeSerializer
    queryset = Size.objects.filter()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
        serializer.instance.plus_one()
```

Comment: What is about best practice? Is it good, when i create adittional ready_for_plus bool field in Model and add if ready_for_plus = True to plus_one method? Idea is to give access to method from API request. Anyway thank, you make it clear, again:).

Comment: @D.Make you are welcome. Not sure but probably it would be better to override model's `save()` method. In this case you will not required doubled save operation.

Comment: got it, so i will do, tnx!

Answer (score 2):

This should be done on serializer level while your `SizeAPIView` remains unchanged:

```
class SizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Size
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, attr, value)

        instance.plus_one()  # performs `instance.save` too.
```

[Documentation on saving instances](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances).