# Call Method in Model Class Based view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have method in my model that I want to be callable in the API.

model:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    PENDING = 'PN'
    ACCEPTED = 'AC'
    DENIED = 'DN'
    BOOKING_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (ACCEPTED, 'Accepted'),
        (DENIED, 'Denied')
    ] 
    createdDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    location = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    operator = models.ForeignKey("Business", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BOOKING_STATUS_CHOICES,default=PENDING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comments
    
    def acceptBooking(self):
        self.status = self.ACCEPTED

    def denyBooking(self):
        self.status = self.DENIED
```

serializer:

```
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('createdDate', 'comments', 'location', 'date', 'operator', 'status')
```

views:

```
class BookingView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer
    queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['createdDate', 'comments', 'location', 'date', 'operator']
```

I would like to call acceptBooking or denyBooking. What's the best practice for achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002135/calling-model-method-via-django-rest-framework-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add [extra actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) to your view. So someone can accept or deny a booking by doing one of these HTTP requests:

```
PUT /bookings/1/accept/
```

```
PUT /bookings/1/deny/
```

You can achieve this with something like:

```py
# models.py
class Booking(models.Model):
    ...
    def accept(self):
        self.status = self.ACCEPTED
        self.save()
    
    def deny(self):
        self.status = self.DENIED
        self.save()
```

```py
# views.py
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

class BookingView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    @action(detail=True, methods=['put', 'patch'])
    def accept(self, request, pk=None):
        booking = self.get_object()
        booking.accept()
        return Response({'status': booking.status})
    
    @action(detail=True, methods=['put', 'patch'])
    def deny(self, request, pk=None):
        booking = self.get_object()
        booking.deny()
        return Response({'status': booking.status})
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your only problem is that you are missing the `self.save()` from the model function. The serializer will automatically save the statuses for you without the functions needed.

If that's not what your looking for and you want to call the functions then as @Ram mentioned, look at how to call the model fields. For you this would be:

```
class BookingView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer
    queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['createdDate', 'comments', 'location', 'date', 'operator']

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
        if <accept_check>:
            serializer.instance.acceptBooking()

        if <deny_check>:
            serializer.instance.denyBooking()
```

Also you must save the changes on model functions like:

```
    def acceptBooking(self):
        self.status = self.ACCEPTED
        self.save()

    def denyBooking(self):
        self.status = self.DENIED
        self.save()
```

Please note functions should use underscores, so `acceptBooking` should be `accept_booking`.